# What is Va.media.tumblr. How it stores post?

Tags: tumblr

I posted a video on my tumblr blog. It gave me a link with va.media.tumblr.com/………mp4

After I deleted my post and visited the same link it was still opening even though there are no posts on my blog anymore.

How does this work?

I was expecting that particular link to be deleted or expire.

Comment: Pretty sure this is standard behaviour, although you would expect that if you deleted a post the media would also be deleted. I don't know if there is some expiry date on the media after which point the images/videos whatever would get removed. I think the only way to know for sure is to message tumblr.

Comment: I decided to investigate and ask Tumblr direct. You can see the thread here https://twitter.com/LukeHarby/status/1616881418533044233?s=20&t=JwIbdy1EyP6KXbFCWTJTbw

Comment: Thank you so much, Luke. I filed a DMCA notice with tumblr and they have disabled the link. Thank you for following this up with tumblr on twitter. Appreciated